# Display product categories and "brand" attribute term names under item name everywhere in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, taxonomy-terms

I want to display the category & attribute (brand) of each product under the product name in the Cart/checkout page

Example:
"Name of product"
"Category | Brand"
[As shown in this image from shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Xnc.png)

I would like to display it the same way on the [cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDS2Q.png)
(and also [Thank you page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VDlR.png) + [Order details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLFXy.png), but these are lower priority)

I have this code which adds the Category to the cart page, but how can i add the attribute/brand next to it? [Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjj5d.png)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'category_under_at_cart', 99, 3);
 
function category_under_at_cart( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
 
$product_item = $cart_item['data'];
 
// make sure to get parent product if variation
if ( $product_item->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
$product_item = wc_get_product( $product_item->get_parent_id() );
} 
 
$cat_ids = $product_item->get_category_ids();
$attributes = $product_item->get_attributes();
 
// if product has categories, concatenate cart item name with them
if ( $cat_ids ) $name .= '</br>' . wc_get_product_category_list( $product_item->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( count( $cat_ids )) . ' ', ' | ','</span>');
 
return $name;
 
}
```

Comment: What attribute is the Brand?

Answer (score 1):

The following will display the formatted product category(ies) and product attribute "brand" term names on minicart, cart, checkout, customer order and email notifications:

```
// Custom funtion that return the formatted category(ies) and attribute 'brand' term names
function get_categories_and_brand_html( $product_id ){
    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $cat_names  = (array) wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', ['fields' => 'names'] );
    $brand_name = $product->get_attribute('brand');
    $output     = '';

    if ( ! empty($cat_names) || ! empty($brand_name) ) {
        $output .= '</br><span class="posted_in">';

        if ( ! empty($cat_names) ) {
            $output .= implode(', ', $cat_names);
        }

        if ( ! empty($cat_names) && ! empty($brand_name) ) {
            $output .= ' | ';
        }

        if ( ! empty($brand_name) ) {
            $output .= $brand_name;
        }
        $output .= '</span>';
    }
    return $output;
}

// Display term names in minicart and cart page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'category_brand_after_cart_item_name', 100, 3 );
function category_brand_after_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $terms_html = get_categories_and_brand_html( $cart_item['product_id'] );

    if ( ! is_checkout() && ! empty($terms_html) ) {
        $item_name .= $terms_html;
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display term names in checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'category_brand_after_checkout_item_name', 100, 3 );
function category_brand_after_checkout_item_name( $quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $terms_html = get_categories_and_brand_html( $cart_item['product_id'] );

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty($terms_html) ) {
        $quantity .= $terms_html;
    }
    return $quantity;
}

// Display term names on customer orders
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', 'category_brand_after_order_item_name', 100, 2 );
function category_brand_after_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    $terms_html = get_categories_and_brand_html( $item->get_product_id() );

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() && ! empty($terms_html) ) {
        $item_name .= $terms_html;
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display term names on email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'category_brand_after_email_item_name', 100, 3 );
function category_brand_after_email_item_name( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    $terms_html = get_categories_and_brand_html( $item->get_product_id() );

    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && ! empty($terms_html) ) {
        $item_name .= $terms_html;
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: on the emails page it needs a line break https://i.imgur.com/x2WVOUX.png

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but any way i can add a line break to the emails? Or call the "category" and "brand" in elementor to just plug them in as needed with my page builder?